# Unable to add to property column in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've created a database using code first migrations with a table called Recordings. However 1 property (RecordingType) was not being added to the database unless I manually updated the migration file. This is all fine and good, but when I run the .Add(Recording) method, the column is not updated. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post code for your model ?

Comment: My guess: not supported datatype. Impossible to tell without seeing appropriate details.

Comment: needed to set RecordType as a property, not a field. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Really annoyed at how simple the answer was:
`public int RecordType;`
doesn't get picked up by EntityFramework, instead it should have been
`public int RecordType{get;set;}`
Sorry for wasting peoples time.